# How do I use a different libstdc++.a with Rust?

Tags: gcc, rust, octave, rustup

I'm using the nightly Rust through rustup. I'm trying to build a Windows dll for GNU Octave. Is it possible to use the libstdc++.a from Octave?

I'm able to compile, but linking [fails with errors](https://gist.github.com/ctaggart/0a2676c24844890c161d6e5720a6b91f) like:

```
C:\Users\camer\.rustup\toolchains\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib/libstdc++.a(locale.o):(.text$_ZNSt6locale5_Impl16_M_install_cacheEPKNS_5facetEy+0x2c): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_lock'

C:\Users\camer\.rustup\toolchains\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib/libstdc++.a(locale.o):(.text$_ZNSt6locale5_Impl16_M_install_cacheEPKNS_5facetEy+0xa7): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_unlock'

C:\Users\camer\.rustup\toolchains\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib/libstdc++.a(locale.o):(.text$_ZNSt6locale5_Impl16_M_install_cacheEPKNS_5facetEy+0xde): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_init'
```

My current hunch is that the `libstdc++.a` that is found isn't compatible. It is finding the one from Rust with this order of search paths:

1. `"-L"
   "C:\Users\camer\.rustup\toolchains\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib"`
2. `"-L" "C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\lib64\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.4"`

The gcc that ships with Octave 4.2.1 is GCC 4.9.4 released [2016-08-03]. Rust nightly has GCC 6.3 released [2016-12-21]. Do I need to do something like compile the Rust standard library with the GCC 4.9.4 from Octave? Is that possible? Full code and more details in this [issue](https://github.com/ctaggart/octh/issues/18#issuecomment-303691573).

Comment: Actually, it seems like you are missing the pthread library. libstdc++ is a C++ library, and Rust should not need it (it would need libc, however).

Comment: That is what it looks like, but `C:\Users\camer\.rustup\toolchains\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libpthread.a` exists and so does `C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\lib\libpthread.dll.a`. `-pthread` is specified, just like in the working C++ build.

Comment: The libpthread.a from Rust is missing the exports, which may be the cause. I logged issue https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42194